# How to inspect javadoc comments?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a library with three artifacts:

```
lib.jar - the lib
lib-sources.jar - sources of the lib
lib-javadoc.jar - a javadoc static site of the lib
```

I want to inspect javadoc comments on the lib and to figure out, for example:

- Do all parameters in interfaces have a javadoc comment (@param).
- Do all not void public methods in classes and interfaces have a javadoc comment (@return).
- etc.

How can I inspect javadoc comments in the lib?

Comment: (1) unzip lib-sources.jar,  scan java file (2) if lib is your project, and you have original source, Maven project, you can use `checkstyle`, `pmd`, `FindBugs` to config some check rules then scan and output some reports.